# Count page views and unique views for a website

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, ip

I made a portfolio website of sorts using bootstrap and html hosted on github pages,

I found a website which gives you the unique views and total views but the problem is it gives an image and it seems to be [insecure](https://sonuishaq67.github.io), so

I was wondering if I could make a program to use the IP or something to count total views and unique views of the website.

Any help will be of great use as I am a novice web developer

Comment: first you have to decide what you mean by "unique". An IP address (by which I mean the public IP address which would be visible to your PHP server) will very rarely identify a single device, let a lone a single individual person. So, on what basis are you hoping to categorise your views? What would make a request "unique" for your purposes?

Comment: Maybe the same way hitwebcounter.com calculates it ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that site, so please explain what criteria they use.

Comment: P.S. "it seems to be insecure"... that's only because you have presumably linked to the other site using HTTP instead of HTTPS, which is what the warnings in the Console are telling you. Just switch to talking to that site via HTTPS (assuming it supports it, which I'd be surprised if it doesn't).

Comment: both websites used are https and the img src in my index.html is https too

Comment: That's not what the warnings are telling you. _Somewhere_ in your code it's using http:// to make a request to that site. Judging by the fact there are two warnings in the console, I'd suggest there are two occurrences of this is in your code (either literally written twice, or 2 requests triggered from a loop or something).

Comment: Don't you want to try tools such as [Google Analytics](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/analytics/)? I guess it would be easier to integrate with them on the server-side and it should be quite accurate as well.

Comment: I just wanted to know how to make a program of such

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Google Analytics https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/
It is a decent method of analysing your audience on the basis of page view count, unique page view count, returning users, demographics, sources of traffic etc.